# Why does the code keep running indefinitely on reading a text file?

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a txt file into a 2d array. The code keeps running indefinitely. I cannot seem to figure out why.

```
public static void loadState() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("large.txt")); //loads txt file instead of keyboard input for scanner
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        ++rows;
        Scanner colReader = new Scanner(input.nextLine());

        while (colReader.hasNextInt()) {
            ++cols;
        }
    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println(cols + "==" + rows);
}
```

Comment: `while(colReader.hasNextInt())` - if you do not read the value then it will remain there.

Comment: Thanks, replacing while with an if loop solved it.

Comment: What is an "if loop"?

Comment: @ScaryWombat already pointed out your issue. Just to make it a little bit clear. The ```hasNext*()``` and ```next*()``` are companion methods. You correctly use them in the case of ```input``` variable -  ```input.hasNextLine()``` (check and control loop) and ```input.nextLine()``` (read and move to the next position). But, ```colReader``` doesn't execute ```colReader.nextInt()```, this companion method is missed in your code. So, your code actually never moves to the next position and keeps checking in an infinite loop.